# First time app run action depending on how app was installed (Android)

Tags: android, installation

We have a native Android App that users will install exclusively from Google Play. We want the first content displayed in the app to change depending on whether the user found the app by themselves by searching in Google Play, or if they followed a link from our website to the Google Play page from a browser.

Is this possible?

How?

Also see related question for [iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707377/first-time-app-run-action-depending-on-how-app-was-installed-ios).

Comment: Btw, you can ask both questions in question too.

Comment: First time they install the app, you can make a request to check the weather and act upon that.

Comment: AFAIK is not doable.

Comment: I have seen so many questions been shot down when they are too broad, I didn't take a chance on it!

Comment: @Carnal: We have a serverside, problem is which request and with which identification? The question is how does the app know where it was installed from?

Comment: You will need to enable GPS position and get lat, long.

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote. I don't get it. At least tell me why so I can improve it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Google Play Install Referrer an pass a different value through depending on the source? ie. Pass in a value if from your website and a blank value if from a search.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tagmanager/InstallReferrerReceiver