# First time app run action depending on how app was installed (iOS)

Tags: ios, installation

We have a native iOS App that users will install exclusively from Appstore. We want the first content displayed in the app to change depending on whether the user found the app by themselves by searching in Appstore or if they followed a link from our website to the Appstore page from a browser.

Is this possible?

How?

Also see related question for [Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30707339/first-time-app-run-action-depending-on-how-app-was-installed).

Comment: I like my questions to sit for a while as there are many smart guys and gals out there that should get their chance before i start marking stuff as acceped.

Comment: I am the eternal optimist :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the launch of iOS8 Apple introduced a new install attribution feature. Unfortunately this does not yet allow for an App to know the value of the query parameter passed in the page view of the appstore that lead to the installation of the app like in Google Play Install Referrer, but it is speculated that this will happen in the future.

In the meantime, the closest thing that will solve this problem albeit with some imperfections is called "Fingerprinted Redirect with URL Parameters" and an article explaining how this works with links to technical example implementation can be found [here](https://attributionapp.com/blog/lets-solve-ios-attribution-methods/).